# Unable to connect to the server : FATAL : Password authentification failed for user "yyyy"

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem when it comes to connecting on somebody database with pgAdmin 4 . My mate have a server witch is for our backEnd project and I want to connect to his server DB . He created a role for me with all the prevelages for all tables. When I'm trying to create a server with a name "clinic" and on Connection section I write on host localhost port is 5000 on witch I installed my pgAdmin so it's a good port , Mainenance database : postgres and username, password   is the one that he created for my with all the privilages. I got this error :
Unable to connect to the server : FATAL : Password authentification failed for user "yyyy"

The way he created my user and give privilages is with this 2 commands :

```
CREATE USER emilut WITH PASSWORD 'passowrd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_name TO username;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRYEx.png)

Here is a screnn share with my problem . Do you have any idea ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pWhh.png)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you tag a postgresql related question with mysql and mysql workbench?

Comment: Is the password really `'passowrd'` and did you use that spelling when connecting?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to doctor the error message to censor your username in two places, while leaving it uncensored in two others.  Look in the server's log file for a more detailed error message.

Comment: Is your mate's database on your local computer?  You say you want to connect to his database, but you seem to be connecting to an unrelated database server you created yourself.

Comment: @jjanes I want to connect to his database. So from what you have told me the problem is that I should look more into how to connect to a remote database ? It's not on create choice?